# get unique data from multi-dimensional array list

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 records from 2 different query results. I have merged those data. but i have to display unique data depends on **vName** key. 
Here is my result:

```
{
    "val1": "9",
    "vName": "abc",
    "bname": "",
    "cname": "",
    "brid": "",
    "cmpid": "154",
    "logo": "",
    "banner": "",
    "description": "",
    "catids": "",
    "type": "company",
    "is_nav": "1",
    "bigthumb_logo": "",
    "compressthumb_logo": "",
    "bigthumb_banner": "",
    "compressthumb_banner": "",
    "sp_ar": "Aperitif"
},
{
    "val1": "9",
    "vName": "abc",
    "bname": "abc",
    "cname": "abc",
    "brid": "341",
    "cmpid": "154",
    "logo": "",
    "banner": "6c497c72bfec4c694c1cc2c49066e7a1.png",
    "description": "http:\/\/www.abc.com\/",
    "catids": "9",
    "sp_ar": "Aperitif",
    "type": "company",
    "is_nav": "1",
    "bigthumb_logo": "40cbcede9429cdb44895e0e6f4c050d2.png",
    "compressthumb_logo": "40cbcede9429cdb44895e0e6f4c050d2.png",
    "bigthumb_banner": "6c497c72bfec4c694c1cc2c49066e7a1.png",
    "compressthumb_banner": "6c497c72bfec4c694c1cc2c49066e7a1.png"
}
```

Expected result should be only one of them, compare with **vName**:

```
{
    "val1": "9",
    "vName": "abc",
    "bname": "",
    "cname": "",
    "brid": "",
    "cmpid": "154",
    "logo": "",
    "banner": "",
    "description": "",
    "catids": "",
    "type": "company",
    "is_nav": "1",
    "bigthumb_logo": "",
    "compressthumb_logo": "",
    "bigthumb_banner": "",
    "compressthumb_banner": "",
    "sp_ar": "Aperitif"
 }
```

How can i get the result?

Comment: So you only want the result to hold values for the properties that are identical? You should clear that up in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the data into an array where the key is your unique value.

You can do something like:

```
$data = array('this is your array of data');
$unique = array();
foreach($data as $value) {
    if(!array_key_exists($value['vName'], $unique)) {
        $unique[$value['vName']] = $value;
    }
}
// $unique now contains only arrays with a unique 'vName', using the first it finds in the original list

$new_array = array_values($unique);
```

Comment: "abc": {
    "val1": "9",
    "vName": "abc",
    "bname": "",
    "cname": "",
    "brid": "",
    "cmpid": "154",
    "logo": "",
    "banner": "",
    "description": "",
    "catids": "",
    "type": "company",
    "is_nav": "1",
    "bigthumb_logo": "",
    "compressthumb_logo": "",
    "bigthumb_banner": "",
    "compressthumb_banner": "",
    "sp_ar": "Aperitif"
 }

i am getting this type of data, i dont want abc: { }

Comment: i don't want data like abc: {}
i want data that starts with {}

Comment: it is making dictionary

Comment: Answer updated, didn't know having an associative array mattered.  I guess you are converting to json?

Comment: yes, i am converting it into json and i want all keys in response also, just now it is displaying only vName

Comment: how can i display all ?

Comment: i did the wrong function, updated it 30 seconds later.  Didn't mean to do array_keys(), should have been array_values() which the answer has now

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a array of associative array stored in `$data`, the following code will filter it based on `vName` and store array of associative arrays with unique `vName` in `$filtered_data`

```
$taken = array();

$filtered_data = array_filter($data, function($value) {
    global $taken;
    if (in_array($value['vName'], $taken)) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $taken[] = $value['vName'];
        return true;
    }
});
```

Here, the variable `$taken` keeps track of all the `vName` values that are currently in the `$filtered_data`. If you find a duplicate `vName` (that is currently there in `$taken`), it discards that element.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, it should work for you.

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize",$input)));
```

Comment: this will only work if each batches are exact copies, if its based on one single value to check duplicates, this will fail